# SQL Query to Map Debit Transaction to Deposited Transaction in FIFO manner

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am seeking help here to Map outgoing debit Transaction to deposit Transaction. Attached is the screen shot on the type of dataset I receive.

explanation of the data -
A customer can buy a Point Pack (Think of this as a Deposit of dollar amount to their account). Customer can use that Deposited dollar amount to active\Renew certain services\products(a debit Charge to their account).What I am looking for here is to Map all the debit Transaction to its deposited transaction on the basis of First In First Out (Fifo). customer can stop using certain product\service and may eligible for a credit(as a refund to their account and the point goes back to pool)

[Original Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcclO.png)

[Desire Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhtff.png)

Thank you for reply.  Here is DDL and sample data.

```
Create Table #salesTran
(customer Varchar(20),
TransactionID varchar(20),
TransactionDate Datetime,
TransactionType Varchar(20),
TransactionSubType Varchar(20),
Points Float,
SerialNumber Varchar(50),
ServiceType Varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC001','1/1/2021 21:20:27', 'Credit','In',100,'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-123','PointPack'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC002','1/2/2021 18:22:36', 'Debit','Out',50,'ABCD-0001','Service A'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC003','1/2/2021 13:56:55', 'Debit','Out',30,'ABCD-0002','Service B'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC004','1/31/2021 20:16:31', 'Credit','In',100,'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-456','PointPack'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC005','2/1/2021 16:21:00', 'Debit','Out',20,'ABCD-0003','Service B'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC006','2/1/2021 16:49:15', 'Credit','Refund',20,'ABCD-0003','Service B'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC007','2/1/2021 16:49:20', 'Debit','Out',30,'ABCD-0003','Service C'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC008','2/1/2021 20:46:42', 'Debit','Out',50,'ABCD-0001','Service A'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC009','2/1/2021 20:21:51', 'Credit','In',50,'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-789','PointPack'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC010','3/2/2021 18:22:36', 'Debit','Out',50,'ABCD-0001','Service A'); 
INSERT INTO #salesTran VALUES ('Cust001','ABC011','3/2/2021 13:56:55', 'Debit','Out',30,'ABCD-0002','Service B');
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would recommend adding the DDL of the table along with a few insert commands to add some sample data. This would clarify the question and also provide someone trying to help with a quick way to test their solution. The easier it is to replicate the issue the quicker and better answers you'll have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have added DDL and some sample data.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please explain what a refund does exactly. Let's call a credit that is exhausted (i.e. zero) "closed" and a credit with still some value above zero "open". I see that the refund in your example reopens the credit that was just closed with the previous row. So, a refund does not add to the first credit that is still open but reopens a closed credit instead. In case there are many closed ones, does it open the first or last closed credit? And only if there are no closed credits yet will it add to the oldest open one? What is the exact rule which credit a refund applies to?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - anytime a Refund is issued it will go back to the current open Credit Pack but if the Credit pack was exhausted and the refund was issued immediately before we started using next Credit pack then the points should be refunded back into the closed Credit. if the debit transaction was fulfilled by two different Credit pack and if that transaction is refunded then the credit should go back into respective pack.

Comment: (I.e. if a debit transaction of 30 points were fulfilled using 10 point from Pack 1 and 20 points from Pack 2 then refund of that transaction will put 10 points back in point Pack 1 and 20 points in Point Pack 2. and next transaction of debit will deduct points   first from Point pack 1 and if its exhausted then use point pack 2 to fulfill same or upcoming debit transactions.

Comment: To be honest, I would just select all rows and then do this with a programming language. While this is possible with SQL (a recursive query that goes from one row to the next and remembers the credit stack on its way), it would be quite complicated.